# Helm upgrade version for specific chartt

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am new to Helm and I would like to update version of the chart that I am using.

When I run `helm list`, I can see:

```
NAME                REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS      CHART                       APP VERSION NAMESPACE      
jenkins             43          Thu Sep 24 08:21:54 2020    DEPLOYED    jenkins-0.35.10             0.35.10     infrastructure
```

I would like to update version of the chart to `jenkins-0.35.1`. I looked into [helm upgrade](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/) command, but it is not really clear for me how to do it.

Can someone help?

I have tried `helm upgrade --install --namespace infrastructure jenkins jenkins-0.35.1`, but I can see this error `Error: failed to download "jenkins-0.35.1" (hint: running` helm repo update `may help)`

Answer (score 0):

Before upgrading the helm chart, it requires to update the chart repository with `helm repo update`, this will update the changes you have made to the chart repositories. `helm repo list` will give the list of the repository you have configured. If you don't have any repo, this will help https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_repository/

However, you can manually package the newer version by running `helm package` command and then upgrade the chart.

```
$ helm ls --short # Here jenkins is my release name
jenkins

$ cd jenkins # into the chart directory

$ helm package . # You will now find a **jenkins-0.35.1.tgz** in the chart folder*

$ helm upgrade jenkins --namespace infrastructure jenkins-0.35.1.tgz
```